# Google BigQuery nested JSON in Power BI

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, powerbi

When I connect to Google BigQuery using Power BI native connector, nested fields are being displayed without column name.

I have followed instructions on https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#loading_nested_and_repeated_json_data

On Power BI, after getting data via BigQuery connector, the column containing nested data is not displaying the column names. Instead, it produces the following output:

```
{
   "v":[
      {
         "v":{
            "f":[
               {
                  "v":"11111"
               },
               {
                  "v":"WA"
               },
               {
                  "v":"Seattle"
               },
               {
                  "v":"123 First Avenue"
               },
               {
                  "v":"1"
               },
               {
                  "v":"current"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "v":{
            "f":[
               {
                  "v":"22222"
               },
               {
                  "v":"OR"
               },
               {
                  "v":"Portland"
               },
               {
                  "v":"456 Main Street"
               },
               {
                  "v":"5"
               },
               {
                  "v":"previous"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

This is the JSON data that I have used to create the BigQuery table:

```
{
   "id":"1",
   "first_name":"John",
   "last_name":"Doe",
   "dob":"1968-01-22",
   "addresses":[
      {
         "status":"current",
         "address":"123 First Avenue",
         "city":"Seattle",
         "state":"WA",
         "zip":"11111",
         "numberOfYears":"1"
      },
      {
         "status":"previous",
         "address":"456 Main Street",
         "city":"Portland",
         "state":"OR",
         "zip":"22222",
         "numberOfYears":"5"
      }
   ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
  {
    "addresses": [
      {
        "zip": "11111",
        "state": "WA",
        "city": "Seattle",
        "address": "123 First Avenue",
        "numberOfYears": "1",
        "status": "current"
      },
      {
        "zip": "22222",
        "state": "OR",
        "city": "Portland",
        "address": "456 Main Street",
        "numberOfYears": "5",
        "status": "previous"
      }
    ],
    "first_name": "John",
    "dob": "1968-01-22",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "id": "1"
  }
```

This is the Power Query M code generated by Power BI

```
let
    Fonte = GoogleBigQuery.Database(null),
    #"outstanding-yew-215518" = Fonte{[Name="outstanding-yew-215518"]}[Data],
    TESTE_Schema = #"outstanding-yew-215518"{[Name="TESTE",Kind="Schema"]}[Data],
    TESTEnativa_Table = TESTE_Schema{[Name="TESTEnativa",Kind="Table"]}[Data]
in
    TESTEnativa_Table
```

Comment: Is there any way to see the query that PowerBI generates?  It seems like the query might be aliasing the field names in a weird way

Comment: @rtenha Just the M code from Power Query.

`let
    Fonte = GoogleBigQuery.Database(null),
    #"outstanding-yew-215518" = Fonte{[Name="outstanding-yew-215518"]}[Data],
    TESTE_Schema = #"outstanding-yew-215518"{[Name="TESTE",Kind="Schema"]}[Data],
    TESTEnativa_Table = TESTE_Schema{[Name="TESTEnativa",Kind="Table"]}[Data]
in
    TESTEnativa_Table`

Answer (score 0):

The workaround that I found for this is using `TO_JSON_STRING(column_name)` function on the query which takes the value and returns a JSON-formatted string representation of the value. More information [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions)

Once you do that you can read the new column on PowerBI same way you read other JSON columns.